# how to draw two connectors in single line in plantuml?

Tags: plantuml

I use follow code to draw my diagram, but the two connector between a <-> b and b <-> c are in two separated line.

```
    participant a
    participant b
    participant c

    a -> b: SESSION-x/XXXX_IND-y
    b -> c: SESSION-x/XXXX_IND-y
```

[how to draw the two connectors like picture in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVODP.png)

Comment: The sequence diagram has messages (not connectors). If you send two messages, even if they have the same name, they are separate. Do you want to just have one message, `a -> c: SESSION-x/XXXX_IND-y`?

Comment: one message will only have one arrowhead at the line, but in the picture, it have two arrowheads, for each target participants